# onChange event not working on IE9/10 when there are other events?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onchange, onkeyup

I'm facing this embarrassing situation. First, I'm on IE 10 right now, but this problem has been detected on IE9 as well. I have this input field and I need 2 events to work on it:
- onKeyUp, to check if the field's value is numeric; and
- onChange, to run some JS when the right number is inputted

If assigned separately, they work just fine. However, whenever I set these 2 events on the input field, the onChange event won't trigger, no matter what. All the other JS on this page has been stripped to prevent interference.

Below is the JS code for the onKeyUp:

```
    <script>
    function CampoNumerico(campo){
                    var valor = campo.value;
        var novoValor = '';
        var pontoPosicao = '';
                    if (isNaN(valor)){ // se nao for numero, devemos retornar o campo ao ultimo valor valido
                            alert(valor + " nao eh um numero valido");
                            novoValor = campo.defaultValue;
                    }
                    else{ //sendo um numero, buscamos a posicao de sua eventual virgula
            valor = valor.split('');
                            for (var i = 0; i < valor.length; i++){
                                    if (valor[i] == '.' && pontoPosicao == ''){
                                            pontoPosicao = i;
                                    }
                            }

            // se nao houver ponto, o novo valor do campo sera igual ao valor de entrada da funcao
            if ( pontoPosicao == ''){
                                    for (var i = 0; i < valor.length; i++){
                                            novoValor += valor[i];
                                    }

            }
            else{ // se houver o ponto, registramos o novo valor igual ao valor de entrada, ate o limite de casas decimais
                var tamanho = ((pontoPosicao + 3) < valor.length)? pontoPosicao + 3 : valor.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
                    novoValor += valor[i];
                }
            }
                            if (pontoPosicao != '' && pontoPosicao < (valor.length - 3)){ // se houver um ponto e mais de 2 casas decimais, alertamos o usario e desconsideramos as casas adicionais
                                    alert("Aviso: " + campo.value + " tem mais de 2 casas decimais; serão consideradas apenas as primeiras casas - " + novoValor);
                            }
                    }
        // terminamos por atualizar o valor do campo
                    campo.value = novoValor;
            } // fim da CampoNumerico

</script>
```

Below is the field I'm trying to assign this script to:

```
<input type='text' name='campo' value='0'  onchange='alert("1")' onkeyup='CampoNumerico(this)'>
```

At this point I just want to alert "1" when the onchange is triggered, but I'm unable to do even this simple action...

Interestingly, this coding works on other browsers just fine - Chrome & Firefox. Can anyone help me with this embarrassing situation? Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

EDIT - input field now visible separately

Comment: Hmm there shouldn't be a problem assigning both attributes. Technically, the better way to do this is by **not** using inline attributes, but instead binding the events in JavaScript with `element.addEventListener`/`element.attachEvent`. Have you checked your browser's console for any errors?

Comment: You need to explain what the intended functionality is? Right now you're iterating over strings multiple times looking for periods and other strangeness, which would be better solved in other ways !

Comment: adeneo, the point of this function is to ensure that the text typed is in a number format like [ 12345.67 ], with only numbers and a maximum of 2 digits after the period, if there's one, so when I use onChange I'll capture a number on the other event.
EDIT: If you know any better ways of doing it, please tell me. I could even work with coin formats [ 12,345.67 ], though this is not really the point. I just don't know a better way of doing this...

Comment: Ian, do you mean to run a script on onLoad event to add the attributes via script? I think I can give this a try, but if you meant something else please let me know.